# Why is the Tomboy Note indicator icon duplicating itself?

Tags: unity, 14.04, icons, tomboy

I have a bug with Tomboy Notes application on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Whenever I boot my system, clicking the original panel, the icon doubles. And every word that I type and delete in the search bar, the icon also doubles.

Another problem, when you click to create new note it appears an error of "Broken" pipe. When I click the icon again, I see that the note was created empty, with current date and time.

Look at the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmYPCUUi0JU).

Comment: Are you using unity-lens-tomboy, which lets you search Tomboy notes from the Dash? That worked fine in 13.10, but in 14.04 it seems broken and caused this same problem on my system.

Comment: It's enabled, but I can't find my notes by the Dash. Anyway, I have disabled for testing.

Comment: Yeah, for me it didn't show notes and also had that bad side effect. I had to remove the package to get prevent the duplication (though of course now I can't search for the notes in the dash).

Comment: @AndréMarinho, how did you disabled the Tomboy Dash Plugin?

Comment: @sergej I selected the Application lens on the Dash. There will show all the Dash Plugins. Right click on the Tomboy plugin and select Disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplication of Tomboy indicator icons is a bug caused by `unity-tomboy-lens`, which is a lens that allowed for searching the contents of Tomboy notes via the Dash in 13.04. There were some issues in 13.10, but overall it still worked; in 14.04, however, it totally ceased to display the notes in the dash, plus caused this bug.

Unfortunately, the developer seems to have stopped using Unity, so the lens will doubtfully be updated (see [this bug report](https://github.com/rrerolle/unity-lens-tomboy/issues/2)).

Comment: I have disabled the Tomboy Dash Plugin and the icon stopped replicating. Thanks!